# plsql reading text file in an array

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

When I run this portion of my code, which is inside a package, I get an error (specifically at the `l_cnt := 1_cnt + 1` line for some reason and the code crashes. What could I be doing wrong? I am trying to read in a file of certs. Here's what I have so far:

```
v_certList arr_claims_t := arr_claims_t();                                  


  v_certLst VARCHAR2(2000); 

  f UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
  s VARCHAR2(200);


-- used for looping
l_cnt simple_integer := 0;

  /*cop procedure*/
  PROCEDURE COP_DATALOAD_V2 AS
    arr_claims arr_claims_t;
    arr_sql    arr_sql_t;
  BEGIN

    f := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('V_COP',
                        'certs_file.txt',
                        'R',
                        2500);

    -- populata our v_certlist of arr_claims_t

       loop
         utl_file.get_line(f, s);
         v_certList.extend();
         l_cnt := l_cnt+1;
         v_certList(l_cnt) := s;
     end loop;
    exception
     when no_data_found then
        utl_file.fclose(f);
```

I want the array to be succesfuly populated given a text file (and I understand this is not the best practice but this is what I will have to do for now)

Comment: This is a very long procedure so..the end is somewhere near the end. What do you mean? The loop will run till the exception.. right? The error is:ORA-06512

Comment: I guess you are extending at wrong place. Please check below: 
       loop
         utl_file.get_line(f, s);        
         l_cnt := l_cnt+1;
         v_certList(l_cnt) := s; v_certList.extend();
     end loop;

Comment: ORA-06512 isn't the error, it just indicates a runtime failure. You need the rest of the stack to see what actually went wrong.

Comment: Where can I see the rest of the stack? I am not really sure how to navigate toad. Is my syntax for reading in a file correct?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the error! The s that it was reading in was too big for the array. This was because empty spaces in the files was included.

```
v_certList.extend(1);
      l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
      v_certList(l_cnt) := substr(s,
                                  0,
                                  10)
```

This fixed it for me.